# CGAL compile error

Tags: cgal

I installed all the required libraries of CGAL, and added all the library path to my makefile while compiling my program on linux, but it still occured compiling error.

This is the content of my makefile

```
//--------------------------------------------------

FLAGS = -Wall -g -std=c++11 -O3 

BOOST_LIB_PATH = -I /usr/include/include/

CGAL_LIB_PATH = -I /usr/local/include/

all : 
    g++ $(FLAGS) $(BOOST) $(CGAL) main.cpp -o main
clean : 
    rm main

//--------------------------------------------------
```

Bellow is the error message while compiling, Please help !

```
//---------------------------------------------------- 

g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 -O3  -I /usr/include/include/ -I /usr/local/include/ main.cpp -o main
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Interval_nt.h:208: undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Interval_nt.h:210: undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/cc5WX5dM.o: In function `~Gmpz_rep':
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpz_type.h:57: undefined reference to `__gmpz_clear'
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpz_type.h:57: undefined reference to `__gmpz_clear'
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpz_type.h:57: undefined reference to `__gmpz_clear'
/tmp/cc5WX5dM.o: In function `CGAL::Gmpz::operator==(CGAL::Gmpz const&) const':
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpz_type.h:154: undefined reference to `__gmpz_cmp'
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpz_type.h:154: undefined reference to `__gmpz_cmp'
/tmp/cc5WX5dM.o: In function `CGAL::Quadratic_program_solution<CGAL::Gmpz>::optimality_certificate_numerators_begin() const':
/usr/local/include/CGAL/QP_solution.h:460: undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/cc5WX5dM.o: In function `CGAL::Gmpz::operator<(CGAL::Gmpz const&) const':
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpz_type.h:152: undefined reference to `__gmpz_cmp'
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpz_type.h:152: undefined reference to `__gmpz_cmp'
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpz_type.h:152: undefined reference to `__gmpz_cmp'
/tmCGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: you need to link with gmp and mpfr

Comment: And link with CGAL. Your Makefile makes no sense, you define variables that you do not use and use variables that you do not define, call LIB things about INCLUDES, etc.

Comment: You may have misunderstanding the meaning of the name of my variable BOOST_LIB_PATH and CGAL_LIB_PATH, those are actually the include paths for boost and CGAL. For the use of CGAL includes headers such  like #include <boost/...> or #include <cgal/...> .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I fix it by adding
find_library( GMP_LIB     NAMES "gmp"          PATHS ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} )
and add it to the target_link_libraries